# How to replace ids with usernames in message.content

Tags: discord, discord.js

the `message.content` shows the ids of users when mentioned in a message.

Does `discord.js` provide a way to replace it with usernames instead?

message in discord.

"hello @imran"

```
${message.content}
```

Result:

hello <@577361951269715988>

Comment: Usernames changes continue. Discord uses the member's user ID instead. `<@userid here>` is basically the same as mentioning the user without using the username. If you wish to print out the username without mention the user, fetch the member in the guild and use `.user.tag` instead.

Comment: what I meant is when I do `message.content` it shows all mentions as ids. Is there a wayto  pass some sort of flag that I need names not ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [cleanContent](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=cleanContent) property.

> The message contents with all mentions replaced by the equivalent text. If mentions cannot be resolved to a name, the relevant mention in the message content will not be converted.

If you need the name of the mentionned person instead, without having to parse, the `message` type has a [mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) property. The `message.mentions` is a [messageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) which has the property [members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members).
It's a collection of [guildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) which has different property, whose `displayName` or `nickname`.

The collection reference every mention to users in the message.